# Returning a substring from a method using java

Tags: java, string

Is there a way of returning substring from a string in java?
For example if I have a string:aadaa
It should return me: {a,a,d,a,a,aa,ad,aa,aad,ada,daa..}
This is my code:

```
String substring(String str1)
{ 
    //String sbs="";
    int len=str1.length();

    for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1;j<=len;j++)
        {
            return(str1.substring(i, j));

        }

    }
```

I need the return statement to return a value from this method not to print it.
Please help.

Comment: what are you trying to do, can you explain in example?

Comment: There are many different substrings of a string. Which substring do you want?

Comment: @Sweeper I want all

Comment: You want every possible combination of substring for any given string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all substrings of a given `String` using Java, you can use this `GetSubtrings` method:

```
public static ArrayList<String> GetSubstrings(String str) {

    // set up any substring and add it to the ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> subStrings = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= str.length() - i; ++j) {
            subStrings.add(str.substring(i, i + j));
        }
    }

    return subStrings;
}
```

An example on how to use it would be:

```
// stores all substrings
ArrayList<String> subStrings = new ArrayList();

// call method to get all substrings
subStrings = GetSubstrings("Test");
```

This will return an ArrayList which contains: { "T", "Te", "Tes", "Test", "e", "es", "est", "s", "st", "t" }

**Whole example program:**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // stores all substrings
        ArrayList<String> subStrings = new ArrayList();

        // call method to get all substrings
        subStrings = GetSubstrings("Test");
    }    

    public static ArrayList<String> GetSubstrings(String str) {

        // set up any substring and add it to the ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> subStrings = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= str.length() - i; ++j) {
                subStrings.add(str.substring(i, i + j));
            }
        }

        return subStrings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the program fails if the string is "aaaa"

Comment: Why do you think it fails? It also returns all substrings but there are duplicates just like within the example of your question. If you do not want duplicate values, use HashSet<String> instead of ArrayList<String> as Trần Nam Trung suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As **oRole**'s answer, if you don't want duplicate values, simply change List to HashSet. Since Java Set doesn't hold duplicate values.

```
public static HashSet<String> GetSubstrings(String str) {

    // set up any substring and add it to the ArrayList
    HashSet<String> subStrings = new HashSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= str.length() - i; ++j) {
            subStrings.add(str.substring(i, i + j));
        }
    }

    return subStrings;
}
```